# observable from array with mergMap: finalize never called

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngxs

I have the following code:

```
// code is in a  state class for ngxs
const someObject = ctx.getState().someObject;
const sourceArray: SomeType[] = [/* content */];

return from(sourceArray).pipe(
  tap((arrayElem) => ctx.patchState({currentElem: arrayElem})),
  switchMap((arrayElem) => {
    return this.someService.someMethod(arrayElem);
  }),
  catchError((err) => {
    return of(err);
  }),
  finalize(() => {
    console.log("Test"); // Never called
  })
);


someMethod(request) {
    return this.someClientAsync().pipe(
      switchMap((theClient) => {
        return new Observable<ReturnType>(subscriber => {
            theClient.makeCall(request, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              subscriber.error(err)
            }
            subscriber.next(data);
          });
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

The problem is: the code in the `switchMap` operator is called correctly, for every array element, but the `finalize` method is never called.

It may be due to the code in `someMethod`: There, I had to wrap code that uses callbacks into an observable. The methods that the object returned by `someClientAsync()` has this callback-style API.

But I am not sure. The way I wrapped the callback into the observable works for other methods in that service. And as I wrote, `switchMap` is actually called n times, n being the array length.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

Thanks all for the posts! Got some really nice information here I wasn't aware of.

I think my problem is the way I wrap the callback-style API into the observable in `someMethod` in the service.

The actual API I need to use looks like this:

```
someClient.doAction(params, (data, err) => {

// callback
});
```

and I would like to convert this into an observable.

I think I need to go with at @martin' answer unless someone thinks it's not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the rxjs docs (https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize), finalize is called when the observable errors or completes.

In your situation, you are catching all errors, therefore the observable never errors. From your example it is unclear if `this.someService.someMethod(arrayElem);` ever completes, but if it is not, the resulting observable will never complete. Therefore, the function inside finalize is never called.

**What to do to solve it?**

Again, it is unclear from your example what you are trying to achieve. However, I will make some assumptions.

- If you only want the first value of `this.someService.someMethod(arrayElem);` and then let it complete, you can do:

```
switchMap((arrayElem) => {
    return this.someService.someMethod(arrayElem).pipe(take(1));
  })
```

- If you want to enforce that `this.someService.someMethod(arrayElem);` emits a value within some time (eg: you want to recover from an http request that did not receive a response), you can use:

```
from(sourceArray).pipe(
  switchMap((arrayElem) => this.someService.someMethod(arrayElem).pipe(take(1))),
  timeout(timeoutTimeInMs),
  finalize(() => console.log("Test")) // Certainly called
);
```

- If you do not want to enforce a value, but you can emit a dummy value if the inner observable does not emit (eg: An http request for which you cannot wait to long but you do not want to throw an error if the request takes a long time):

```
from(sourceArray).pipe(
  switchMap((arrayElem) => this.someService.someMethod(arrayElem).pipe(
    take(1), 
    timeout(timeoutTimeInMs),
    catchError(() => of(dummyValue)) 
  )),
  finalize(() => console.log("Test")) // Certainly called
);
```

**Btw:**
`switchMap` is similar, but not the same as `mergeMap`. If `switchMap` receives a second value before the inner observable of the first value completes, it will dispose the first inner observable and subscribe to the second observable. `mergeMap` will subscribe to both observables in the same situation. `concatMap` will wait for the first one to complete and then subscribe to the second observable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the some method so that it just resolves with the callback like so? The Observable wrapper is not necessary if `makeCall` returns an observable!

```
someMethod(request) {
    return this.someClientAsync().pipe(
      switchMap((theClient) => {
        return theClient.makeCall(request);
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`finalize()` is a dispose handler that is called when a chain is being disposed. This happens after the chain is completed with a `complete` notification or when the chain is unsubscribed.

In your case you never complete the merged Observable:

```
return new Observable<ReturnType>(subscriber => {
  theClient.makeCall(request, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      subscriber.error(err)
    }
    subscriber.next(data);
  });
});
```

This is actually creating a memory leak. You need to properly complete the Observable if you're done emitting.

```
return new Observable<ReturnType>(subscriber => {
  theClient.makeCall(request, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      subscriber.error(err);
      return;
    }
    subscriber.next(data);
    subscriber.complete(); // <---
  });
});
```

Btw, ideally you should also return a dispose function from `new Observable()` to cancel the request created with `theClient.makeCall(request, ...)` but maybe it's not possible in your case.